# How do I make the images fit for all kind of devices

Tags: html

I am Adding a image slide bar below the menu bar. It is perfectly fitting to all kind of devices. So what can I do to fit for all kinds of devices.

Comment: What image ? Using `img` tag or using `background-image` in CSS ?

Comment: Use percentages for width and height?

Comment: Search `responsive` on Google.

Comment: Please explain what you are trying to do, best would be with code.

Comment: using img tag @Merianos Nikos

Comment: Thank you every one for your responce

Answer (score 0):

Follow this code

```
<div class="slidebar">
<img src="https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/img/sprites.svg?v=8c1c8cba242e">
</div>
```

CSS

```
.slidebar{
  width:100%;
  height:auto;
  overflow:hidden;
}

.slidebar img{
  width:100%;
  height:auto;
}
```

Working Demo https://jsfiddle.net/Rahul_Ravi/6kqxwjz8/